# AWS step function: Use nested variable inside condition

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless, aws-step-functions

I am are trying to write a step function where each function.

Let's say this is the output of one of the function is

```
{ 
    ...
    "foo": {
      "1": "one"
      "2": "two", 
      "5": "five"
     },
    "current": 2
    ...
}
```

I have a choice statement, which needs to check what is the value of `test_key` and dereference it in `foo` dictionary.

```
...
"ChoiceState": {
      "Type" : "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.foo['$.current']",  <--- This is unsupported
          "StringEquals": "two",
          "Next": "TwoFunction"
        }, 
        {
          "Variable": "$.foo['$.current']",  <--- This is unsupported
          "StringEquals": "three",
          "Next": "ThreeFunction"
        }
        ...
      ],
      "Default": "DefaultFunction"
    }
...
```

How do I use dynamic reference in choice states?

Answer (score 1):

JSONPath doesn't support dynamic keys so this isn't possible. You have to restructure your input data or combine multiple Choice Rules with the `And` comparison operator to check the corresponding property based on `current`:

```
{
  "And": [
    {
      "Variable": "$.current",
      "StringEquals": "2"
    },
    {
      "Variable": "$.foo.2",
      "StringEquals": "two"
    }
  ],
  "Next": "TwoFunction"
}
```